# Not found route doesn't catch nested routes in React Router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement a 404 page with React Router 6. The documentation suggests to use a catch-all route:

- https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route
- https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#not-found-routes

Thing is that in my case I have nested routes, something like:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Root />} />
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>;
```

This work fine when visiting `/foo`, the not found component is displayed.

But if I visit `/dashboard/foo`, I get a blank page.

Tried several combinations adding the catch-all route to the nested routes but still getting a blank page:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Root />} />
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

What I'm missing? How can I set up a single 404 page properly?

Comment: Is the `Dashboard` component rendering descendent routes? Can you share all relevant code? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It turned out to be a problem with Webpack config, has nothing to do with React Router.